# How does Rsyslog categorizes logs into the various severity levels?

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

Also, can you provide me some resources to learn about logs in details - how many different types of logs are there, which system processes generate which types of logs,etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a standard in unix logging, you save logs in one of a few different priorities, like WARNING, ERROR or INFO, so you can filter them out for debugging issues. How it happens would depend on the system that is logging out.

A good place to start would probably to read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level) page on syslog as that explains the fundamentals.